# HashMap ignoring overridden hashCode and equals methods

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode

I am loading data on network traffic from a file. The information I'm loading is attacker IP address, victim IP address, and date. I've combined these data into a `Traffic` object, for which I've defined the `hashCode` and `equals` functions. Despite this, the `HashMap` I'm loading them into treats identical `Traffic` objects as different keys. The entire Traffic object complete with some simple test code in the `main` method follows:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Traffic {

    public String attacker;
    public String victim;
    public int date;

    //constructors, getters and setters

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        long attackerHash = 1;
        for (char c:attacker.toCharArray()) {
            attackerHash = attackerHash * Character.getNumericValue(c) + 17;
        }

        long victimHash = 1;
        for (char c:victim.toCharArray()) {
            victimHash = victimHash * Character.getNumericValue(c) + 17;
        }

        int IPHash = (int)(attackerHash*victimHash % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return (IPHash + 7)*(date + 37) + 17;
    }

    public boolean equals(Traffic t) {
        return this.attacker.equals(t.getAttacker()) && this.victim.equals(t.getVictim()) && this.date == t.getDate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Traffic a = new Traffic("209.167.099.071", "172.016.112.100", 7);
        Traffic b = new Traffic("209.167.099.071", "172.016.112.100", 7);
        System.out.println(a.hashCode());
        System.out.println(b.hashCode());

        HashMap<Traffic, Integer> h = new HashMap<Traffic, Integer>();
        h.put(a, new Integer(1));
        h.put(b, new Integer(2));
        System.out.println(h);
    }
}
```

I can't speak to the strength of my hash method, but the outputs of the first two prints are identical, meaning it at least holds for this case.

Since a and b are identical in data (and therefore `equals` returns true), and the hashes are identical, the `HashMap` should recognize them as the same and update the value from 1 to 2 instead of creating a second entry with value 2. Unfortunately, it does not recognize them as the same and the output of the final print is the following:

```
{packagename.Traffic@1c051=1, packagename.Traffic@1c051=2}
```

My best guess at this is that `HashMap`'s internal workings are ignoring my custom `hashCode` and `equals` methods, but if that's the case then why? And if that guess is wrong then what is happening here?

Comment: The `@Override` annotation exists for a good reason. Use it. (And don't reinvent String's hash code, just call it.) (And "two objects are identical if their hash codes match" is a terrible way to define equality.)

Comment: have you tried to call `a.equals(b)` and check if it's `true` ?

Comment: @OrestSavchak That would probably provide a false positive in this case.

Comment: @chryslis I did use the @Override annotation, please read my code before commenting. Also, `equals` does return true, and I'm struggling to see how that would be a false positive since every variable's value is identical.

Comment: @chrylis yeah, you're right, it'll call overloaded method

Comment: @chryslis As for the bad definition of the `equals` method, that was an older placeholder code that I had accidentally copied. See edit.

Comment: @Ecko you used `@Override` on `hashCode()`, not on `equals(Traffic)`. I suspect chrylis was referring to the fact you'd not used it consistently.

Comment: @Ecko "Also, equals does return true, and I'm struggling to see how that would be a false positive" you're not calling the same method that `HashMap` does. Try invoking `a.equals((Object) b)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is your `equals` method, which does not override `Object#equals`. To prove this, the following will **not** compile with the `@Override` annotation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Traffic t) {
    return this.attacker.equals(t.getAttacker()) && 
        this.victim.equals(t.getVictim()) && 
        this.date == t.getDate();
}
```

The implementation of `HashMap` uses `Object#equals` and **not** your custom implementation. Your `equals` method should accept an `Object` as a parameter instead:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Traffic)) {
        return false;
    }

    Traffic t = (Traffic) o;

    return Objects.equals(attacker, t.attacker) &&
        Objects.equals(victim, t.victim) &&
        date == t.date;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves it nicely. The bad definition of the `equals` method was old placeholder code I accidentally copied into the question; I edited the question to reflect the correct code. I had tried adding an @Override annotation, but since I was mistakenly using a `Traffic` as my parameter instead of an `Object`, it threw an error and I deleted it.

Comment: @Ecko I just noticed and edited the answer to accommodate that.